# Should we [transit] away from this tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There's 1379 questions tagged [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit), and 530 questions tagged [transit-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit-visas). For what it's worth, there's [124 with both](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit-visas+transit) and 56 with transit, transit-visas, and visas. If you add on your citizenship and what country you're interested in, that's your quota of 5 tags used up.

The tag wiki for "transit" mentions the tag "transit-visa", but doesn't give any guidance on when to use which tag, nor does the tag wiki "transit-visa".

Should we discourage the use of the "transit" tag, or at least provide guidance when to use "transit" and when to use "transit-visas"?

This was prompted by [Korean transit visa required for Indian?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110091/korean-transit-visa-required-for-indian) , which was tagged "visas air-travel transit seoul" and is now tagged "visas air-travel indian-citizens transit-visas south-korea".

Comment: No. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Comment: @choster what were you referring to from that post?

Comment: We get a number of questions about transits that don't involve transit visas (such as "is my layover too short?" and "do I need to change terminals?"), so I think there's value in keeping the tag, but more guidance would help clarify this.

Comment: Why is any question tagged both [tag:visas] and [tag:transit-visas]? Either they're asking about transit visa specifically, or they're guessing it might be important and they're asking about visas generally so transit-visas would be a meta tag.